# Android Unable to stop media player?

Tags: android

I have link like as ,`String myVideolink = http://www.tnp.sg/fk/lionscheers/test/bgm.mp3`

When call as

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myVideolink));
            startActivity(intent);
```

It plays nice in my Sony Ericsson Xperia, but when I press back, it does not stop.I want to stop it ,How to stop it?

Comment: This could be a bug of Sonys media player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don´t you create a `MediaPlayer` inside the activity?

You can try to do this in `onCreate`:

```
 String myVideolink = http://www.tnp.sg/fk/lionscheers/test/bgm.mp3
 MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(myVideolink));
```

When you want to start yout `MediaPlayer` you must use:

```
mp.start();
```

And you want to stop it when you press the back button. You can do this in the activity.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

            mp.stop();

    }
```

I hope this can be usefull for you.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;

public class myclass extends Activity{

    private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    prepareMediaPlayer();
}


    // prepare the media player
    public void prepareMediaPlayer()
    {
        try {

            mp.setDataSource("http://www.tnp.sg/fk/lionscheers/test/bgm.mp3");

            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

            mp.prepareAsync();

            mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
                    //buttonRecord.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {}
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {} 
        catch (IllegalStateException e) {}


    }
}
```

You can overried onPause OR can use player.stop() etc